# Animated time series map in Power Point presentation

Tags: time-series, animation, powerpoint

I am trying to create an animated map in Power Point. The map needs to visualize the states and municipalities that have adopted a specific policy over time. For example, when a state adopted the policy it would turn a different color. When I get to the Power Point slide I would like to click a button that show the progression of adoption. Basically over the course of the animation you'll see more and more states turning the color of adoption.
While I can create individual maps and put them on separate slides, I'd like to know if there is a program that can do this automatically.

Comment: You may use the temporal controller to create the animation then batch export as image and create a video or animated GIF (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html?highlight=temporal#time-based-control-on-the-map-canvas)